# Insert value into matrix using an equation in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to insert values into my matrix in R using equations. Every time I do that, I get the error "subscript out of bounds."

Edit: Here are the results from my attempt

For example:
`matrix["60","70"] = 1` puts in a value of `1` at my row named `"60"`, column named `"70"` in the matrix

`matrix[lakes[k],lakes2[k]] = 1` gives me the error

I've double checked, and `lakes[k]` and `lakes2[k]` give me `60` and `70`, respectively. I've tried putting `""` around `lakes[k]` and `lakes2[k]` as well.

```
> k=2
> lakes[k]
[1] 70
> lakes2[k]
[1] 60
> lakes_matrix[lakes[k],lakes2[k]] = 1
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, lakes[k], lakes2[k], value = 1) : 
  subscript out of bounds
> lakes_matrix["70","60"] =1
> lakes_matrix
     25 63 1567 40 50 60 70 80
25   NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
63   NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
1567 NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
40   NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
50   NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
60   NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
70   NA NA   NA NA NA  1 NA NA
80   NA NA   NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Could you post proper R code showing your attempt?

Comment: Thank you! That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subset with bracket notation, the way in which R interprets your command will be different based on if you pass a value of type `character` or type `numeric`. In your first example, you pass in 2 values of type `character`

```
lakes_matrix["70","60"]
```

This returns the value of the cell at the row **named** `"70"` and the column **named** `"60"`. That it, it searches through `rownames(lakes_matrix)` and `colnames(lakes_matrix)` for a match

In your second example, however, your vector `lakes` has values of type `numeric` (you can see that because they print without quotation marks around them). So these 2 statements are identical

```
lakes_matrix[lakes[k],lakes2[k]] 
lakes_matrix[70, 60]
```

When you provide numbers, R subsets by **index**. So it tries to return the value of the 70th row and 60th column. Since `lakes_matrix` only has 8 rows and 8 columns, that value doesn't exist and it returns a `subscript out of bounds` error.

---

You can use `as.character` to change the values of `lakes` to type `character`.